# Loop with 3 or 2 items to unpack in Python

Tags: python

I have a for loop that will have 2 or 3 items to unpack. To clarify the loop will have a length of 2 for all elements or 3 for all elements. Not 2 and 3 alternating within one loop. And right now I have the each `for` loop in an `if` statement, which works but also seems cluttered.  I am only checking the first element and assuming the rest will have the same number of items. Is there a more efficient way to write this?

```
    if len(self.choices[0]) == 3:
        for value, label, other in self.choices:
            yield (value, label, other, selected)    
    else:
        for value, label in self.choices:
            yield (value, label, None, selected)
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty good. I like on it, you keep the test out of the inner block of the loop. This makes it much faster.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky So that's faster huh?

Comment: The try/except Value error is a bit faster then yours, but in case, `self.choices` is a generator, it might skip processing the first item, if you have 2 values only (the `for` loop does `self.choices.next()`). So your solution seems in that case safer.

Comment: Seeing your `self.choices[0]` it is clear, you have `list` in `self.choices`, so my concern about consumed item does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe...?

```
for choice in self.choices:
    value, label = choice[:2]
    try:
        other = choice[2]
    except IndexError:
        other = None
    yield (value, label, other, selected)
```

Frankly I'd rather do:

```
try:
    for value,label,other in self.choices:
        yield (value, label, other, selected)
except ValueError:
    for value, label in self.choices:
        yield (value, label, None, selected)
```

If `self.choices` is a list of lists:

```
for choice in self.choices:
    if len(choice) == 2:
        choice.append(None)
    yield tuple( [el for el in choice] + [selected] )
```

Comment: Both are pretty darn smart. Sheesh.

Comment: it's a tuple. So can't append to a tuple. `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
extra = () if len(choices[0]) == 3 else (None,)
for x in choices:
    yield x + extra + (selected,)
```

Comment: Since all elements in `choices` are assumed to be the same length, it's wasteful to check the length every time.

Comment: @EMS - The author actually says that he wants to check all elements for their length rather than just the first element ...

Comment: @ssm No. I am saying that I am only checking the first. I did not say I want to check all did I?

Comment: @ssm The author explicitly says the opposite.

Comment: @EMS: That's true. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to just concat tuples ...

```
for s in self.choices: 
    yield (s + (selected) if len(s) == 3 else s + (None, selected))
```

EDIT:

If all elements are the same length, then just check it once:

```
three = len(self.choices[0]) == 3

for s in self.choices: 
    yield (s + (selected) if three else s + (None, selected))
```

Comment: Since all elements in choices are assumed to be the same length, it's wasteful to check the length every time.

Comment: No need to check `len` on every loop. All are assumed to be either 3 in len or 2 in len